# Requesting permissions in apps

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I was wondering if there is a way to request permissions with the built-in iPhone messages app?

I am very inexperienced with Swift when it comes to permissions requests and I want to know what I can and can't do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't request permissions with the built-in iPhone Messages app. But you can communicate with the Messages app with url scheme.

Url scheme reference about sms can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/SMSLinks/SMSLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH7-SW1

For example, you can do something like this in your app:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "sms:")!) // raise Message app

UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "sms:1-408-555-1212")!) // raise Message app and prepare to send message to 1-408-555-1212
```